# aspose mail merge layout not follow word template

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

I use aspose word, create a datatable, add column, and then mail merge with the word template. But I find in the output, the column width is very different from the word template (e.g. the last column "last date of duty"), why?

The code is as follows:

```cs
DataTable tableOrders = new DataTable("Orders");
tableOrders.getColumns().add("rank");
tableOrders.getColumns().add("staffNo");
tableOrders.getColumns().add("name");
tableOrders.getColumns().add("idNo");
tableOrders.getColumns().add("nature");
tableOrders.getColumns().add("effDate");
tableOrders.getColumns().add("b4effDate");
while(i.hasNext()) {
    Object[] rs = (Object[]) i.next();
    String rank = rs[0]==null?"":rs[0].toString();
    String staffNo = rs[1]==null?"":rs[1].toString();
    String name = rs[2]==null?"":rs[2].toString();
    String id_no = rs[3]==null?"":rs[3].toString();
    String nature = rs[4]==null?"":rs[4].toString();
    String effDate = rs[5]==null?"":(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).format(rs[5]);
    String lastDutyDate = rs[6]==null?"":(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")).format(rs[6]);
    // Create the orders table.
    tableOrders.getRows().add(rank, staffNo, name, id_no, nature, effDate, lastDutyDate);
}
doc.getMailMerge().executeWithRegions(tableOrders);
doc.getMailMerge().execute(new String[] {"currentDate"}, new String[] {sdf2.format(new Date())});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you are saving your output document as PDF. The problem might occur because your table layout is built improperly. But it is difficult to say without your a real document. You can post your question and attach your document in Aspose.Words [support forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/words/8).

Also, you can try configuring your template to use `Fixed Column Width`.

[image]

Most likely, in your template, auto fit behavior is set to `AutoFit to Contents` and after executing mail merge column widths are adjusted according to the data.

Comment: "you can try configuring your template to use Fixed Column Width", yes, this fix my problem, thanks.